# How do I post my XML string to web service rather than an xml file

Tags: xml, go, httprequest

I have sucessfully posted an http request to a web service running on one of our servers.

Please note I did not write the web service and have no access to the source code.

Working code:

```
resp, err := http.Post("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/webservice/", "c:\\xml\\test.xml", nil)
```

I now instead of using an xml file need to build up the xml from a list of values.

I have written a function that does this, it basically pieces together the xml in a string builder. and my output string looks correct.

What I am not sure of is how do I post the xml as the post function seems to take the path to a file rather than a string?

Also is building it together as a string the correct method or should I approach it differently?

Comment: [Read the manual](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Post): `func Post(url, contentType string, body io.Reader) (resp *Response, err error)`. The second argument is the content type, not a filename. The third argument is the body. "piecing together the xml in a string builder" is almost certainly incorrect. Use [the xml package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) instead.

Comment: What does "about tho port an http request" mean? There's apparently a typo in there, but I can't make sense of it to correct the typo.

Comment: edited to make clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you took

```golang
resp, err := http.Post("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/webservice/", "c:\\xml\\test.xml", nil)
```

from. [The docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Post) say the signature of `net/http.Post` is

```golang
func Post(url, contentType string, body io.Reader) (resp *Response, err error)
```

That is, the second parameter is the [content type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type) of the payload to be sent, and the third is the source from which to read the data to be sent.

Hence, if you have a string containing the XML data
(building an XML document using string operations is almost always a wrong thing to do but let's not digress for now),
you can have an `io.Reader` to read data from it by calling
`strings.NewReader()` on your string.

So the call would become

```golang
resp, err := http.Post("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/webservice/", "application/xml", strings.NewReader(yourStringWithXML))
```